# Differences between value and ngValue in Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular-forms

Today I realized about an unexpected (for me) behaviour of the reactive forms in Angular 5. The server was receiving from the app an string with the value "null" instead of the null value, whichh is what I wanted.

I did the following test:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rjrspr?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

As you can see in the picture below, if I use `[value]="null"` in the select, the field is getting "null" (string literal) as value. However, if I use `[ngValue]="null"` it gets the expected `null` value.

[image]

I thought that using `value` was intended for reactive forms, while `ngValue` was for template driven forms. I'd like to know if it's safe to use both in my forms (I always use reactive forms) and if there's any explanation for the different behaviour.

Thanks!

Comment: value always will be a string, ngValue can be an object or whatever

Comment: So, keeping in mind this difference, I assume that it's ok to use `value` or `ngValue` in reactive forms, isn't it?

Answer (score 139, accepted):

Its ok to use `value`or `ngValue`.

The only difference between two is that `value` is always string,  where in `ngValue` you can pass object

Comment: thank you , I could got this from docs angular.io/api/forms/NgSelectOption +1

Answer (score 22):

`const items = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]`

```
<option *ngFor="let item of items" [value]="item">
    {{item}}
</option>
```

using `[value]` when one of the options is selected the value will be `foo`, `bar`, `baz`

```
<option *ngFor="let item of items" [ngValue]="item">
    {{item}}
</option>
```

using `[ngValue]` when one of the options is selected the value will be `0: foo`, `1: bar`, `2: baz`

Answer (score 9):

ngValue is valuable when you need to bind to object in the object collection instead of string that is displayed by option element as an example as follows.

```
  <select [(ngModel)]='selectedColor'>
    <option *ngFor="let color of colors" [ngValue]="color"  >{{color.name}}</option>
  </select>
```

where

```
  colors: [{code:'#FF0000', name:'Red'}, {code:'#00FF00', name:'Green'}, {code:'#0000FF', name:'Blue'}];
```

selectedColor is one of the color object above.

Answer (score 5):

there is no much diffrence between value or ngValue.

The only difference is that,

when you have **`String` as input then use `value`** and

when **`Object` as input then use  `ngValue`**.

```
const colors= ["Red", "Green", "Blue"];

<option *ngFor="let color of colors" [value]="color">
    {{color}}
</option>
```

Answer (score 4):

`value` must be string but `ngValue`- is whatever you want. Value will not bind to selectlist if value type is int not string.