# Access value of option in select and pass it to function - Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an angularForm and a combobox which is filled with options from the database. I need to get the selected option and pass it to a function on button click

```
<div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" formControlName="product" #product>
        <option *ngFor="let product of products" [value]='product'>{{product.name}}</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <button (click)="addFeature(name.value, description.value,product.value)" [disabled]="angForm.pristine || angForm.invalid" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
</div>
```

When I click the button and `console.log` product.value I get `[object,object]`, how to fix this?

```
addFeature(name, description, product) {
    console.log(product);
    // this.featureservice.addFeature(name, description,product);
    // this.router.navigate(['/features/index']);
    // location.reload();
}
```

**UPDATE**

The values in the combobox are filled by:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getProducts();
}

getProducts() {
    this.productservice.getProducts().subscribe(res => {
        this.products = res;
    })
}
```

Comment: try this [value]='product.value'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the whole object, if you need name or description , access it as

```
addFeature(name, description, product) {
  console.log(product.name);
}
```

**EDIT**

You can use ngModel and access the variable directly

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedProduct" formControlName="product" #product>
        <option *ngFor="let product of products" [value]='product'>{{product.name}}</option>
</select>
```

and you can access it as,

```
addFeature() {
  console.log(this.selectedProduct);
}
```

Comment: can you try what you get when you put console.log(JSON.stringify(product)) and post here

Comment: {"0":{},"1":{},"__zone_symbol__changefalse":[{"type":"eventTask","state":"scheduled","source":"HTMLSelectElement.addEventListener:change","zone":"angular","runCount":2}],"__zone_symbol__blurfalse":[{"type":"eventTask","state":"scheduled","source":"HTMLSelectElement.addEventListener:blur","zone":"angular","runCount":2}]}

Comment: is what i get when
<button (click)="addFeature(name.value, description.value,product)"
and
console.log(JSON.stringify(product))

Comment: check updadted answer

Comment: did it fix the issue

Comment: no still didnt fix it :'(

I forgot to add in my question that the values in the select are filled by

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getProducts();
  }
  getProducts() {
    this.productservice.getProducts().subscribe(res => {
      this.products = res;
    })
  }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169663/discussion-between-lars-suffys-and-sajeetharan).

Answer (score 1):

Bind to `ngValue` instead `value` of the option tag:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <select class="form-control" formControlName="product" #product>
    <option *ngFor="let product of products" [ngValue]='product'>{{product.name}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

See [Differences between value and ngValue in Angular 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49918687/differences-between-value-and-ngvalue-in-angular-5) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get your doubt precisely but try to change your select tag to something like so:

```
<select class="form-control" formControlName="product" #product>
   <option *ngFor="let product of products" [value]='product.value'
       {{product.name}}
   </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself

```
    <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]='selectedOption' formControlName="product" #product>
        <option *ngFor="let product of products" [ngValue]='product'>{{product.name}}</option>
      </select>

    <button (click)="addFeature(name.value, description.value,selectedOption.name)" [disabled]="angForm.pristine || angForm.invalid" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
```