# Angular 7: Select Option value is parsed into "[index]: [value]"

Tags: angular, select, angular7, angular-ngmodel

I am using Angular 7. And when I try to bind the value of a `select` to a variable, the value is always parsed into something like "0: 25", "1: 50", "2: 75".

Example code below is for selecting a page size for a paginator. Where `pageSizeOptions = [25, 50, 75, 100]`. Expected behavior is that `pageSize`, bound to `[(ngModel)]`, should contain a `number` type and not a string. Using `[value]` will return a stringified version of the value nd `ngValue` returns the `"[index]: [value]"` format.

```
    <select
      class="form-control"
      (change)="onSelectPageSize($event.target.value)"
      [ngModel]="pageSize"
    >

      <option *ngFor="let size of pageSizeOptions; let i = index" [ngValue]="size">
        {{ size }}
      </option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Can you please make a [Stackblitz](http://stackblitz.com) for this.

Comment: I'll try to find time reproducing it on a Stackblitz, currently just fixed it with manual parsing to int and using `[value]` instead of `[ngValue]`.

Comment: @ColdCerberus check it [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mxjedo?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: @developer033, Thanks. It's weird that when I added an onchange event to `console.log` the `pageSize`, it's actually a number and not similar to what I have here locally.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using ngValue instead of value attribute .

```
<option *ngFor="let size of pageSizeOptions; let i = index" [value]="size">
    {{ size }}
  </option>
```

The difference between ngvalue and value attribute is that value is always string, where in ngValue you can pass object.

Refer this answer for more info [Differences between value and ngValue in Angular 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49918687/differences-between-value-and-ngvalue-in-angular-5)