# How to use multiple variables in the [value] attribute of an input in Angular

Tags: html, angular, input, data-binding, default-value

I have a problem, I would like to do this:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Period:</mat-label>
  <input matInput [value]="period.month / period.year" disabled>
</mat-form-field>
```

But that does not work.

[image]

---

On the other hand, this works:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Period:</mat-label>
  <input matInput [value]="period.year" disabled>
</mat-form-field>
```

Would anyone have a solution to display multiple variables in the value of an input?

**EDIT:** `[ngValue]` does not work, I want to display a string of variables.

Comment: Yes the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `[value]` needs a string, you could set its value to

```
[value]="period.month + '/' + period.year"
```

which resolves to a string. In your code, `period.month` is divided by `period.year` and resolves to `NaN` if at least one of them cannot be changed to a number.

Answer (score 1):

I think`[value]` only supports strings. Try `[ngValue]` instead.

[Differences between value and ngValue in Angular 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49918687/differences-between-value-and-ngvalue-in-angular-5)

Comment: It does not work, I want to display a string of variables.

Answer (score 0):

`[value]` always accepts **String** as an input, but `[ngValue]` accepts **Object**. Try using `[ngValue]`