# When do I use [value] and / or [ngValue] or when not?

Tags: angular

I have worked with angular for a few years now and I have used both **`[value]`** and **`[ngValue]`** and I understand how it works - In **`[value]`**: I can only send a specific value while in **`[ngValue]`**: I can send a complete object but I It generates a bit of confusion at which moment I should use one and the other since with both of them I can get to get the data.

Comment: value is for string and ngValue for objects

Comment: @NagaSaiA thanks ! But when loading let's say a **select** which one is better to use?

Comment: as per official anfular documentation, even for select, https://angular.io/api/forms/NgSelectOption , ngValue - Tracks the value bound to the option element. Unlike the value binding, ngValue supports binding to objects. and value - Tracks simple string values bound to the option element. For objects, use the ngValue input binding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*[ngValue]* when the value is and object as example select elemnt option

```
 const options = [{..} , {..} ,{..} ,{..}]

 <option *ngFor="let opt of options" [ngValue]="opt">{{opt.name}}</option>
```

*[value]* when the value just primitive value like number ,boolean,string

```
 const options = [{..} , {..} ,{..} ,{..}]

 <option *ngFor="let opt of options" [value]="opt.id">{{opt.name}}</option>
```

Comment: When you use [value] and your actual value is a number or boolean it gets converted to a string. You have to convert it back again. If you're trying to deal with a nullable number and null as a possible value it gets converted to an empty string which isn't null so you need to explicitly code to convert that too.

Answer (score 1):

```
`const items = ["one", "two"] `

<option *ngFor="let item of items" [value]="item">
    {{item}}
</option>
```

using `[value]` when one of the options is selected the value will be `one`, `two`

```
<option *ngFor="let item of items" [ngValue]="item">
    {{item}}
</option>
```

using `[ngValue]` when one of the options is selected the value will be `0: one`, `1: two`

when you have String as input then use value and

when Object as input then use  ngValue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a duplicate of: [Differences between value and ngValue in Angular 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49918687/differences-between-value-and-ngvalue-in-angular-5).

- `[value]` is a dynamic attribute. Each attribute of an HTML element can be dynamic (e.g.: the `[href]` attribute of a `<a>` tag, or even the `[src]` attribute of an `<img>` tag. All of this dynamic attributes only take **strings**
- `[ngValue]` is a directive that provide extra services that `value` doesn't provide: in this case, passing **objects** that you can't pass to `[value]`