# Angular Material autocomplete use object attribute as value

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a list of object I want to use in a AutoComplete. When a option gets selected the formConttrol gets the value of the selected item. Now I don't care about the entire object, I only care about the ID.I changed the option to have the id as value, but then the textinput remains empty.

```
  <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option.id">
    {{option.name}}
  </mat-option>
```

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b97y6e-jwm2jq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fautocomplete-display-example.ts

Is there any way to use a object attribute as value?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that [value] is always string. Use [ngValue] instead. Here you can pass objects and numbers (which are objects in javascript) etc.

[Differences between value and ngValue in Angular 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49918687/differences-between-value-and-ngvalue-in-angular-5)

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [ngvalue]="option.id">
    {{option.name}}
</mat-option>
```

Comment: Could you edit the example to show me how that works>?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you bind wrong value here-> `[value]="option.id"`

**Solutation**

```
  <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
    {{option.name}}
  </mat-option>
```

in your `filteredOptions` there is not any `id` paramater that's why its not working
So,

Change `[value]="option.id"` to `[value]="option"`

it will be work fine !
check updated code

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b97y6e-hsmvqn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fautocomplete-display-example.html

Comment: The option indeed has no `id` the example was incorrect. I updated it.